# How to access docker volumes on a Synology NAS

Tags: docker, nas, synology, matrix-synapse

I am trying to get a Matrix Synapse server running on my Synology NAS through docker.

When I run the `generate` command to get the intial homeserver.yaml, it does get generated :

> $ sudo docker run -it --rm     --mount type=volume,src=synapse-config,dst=/data     -e SYNAPSE_SERVER_NAME=my.matrix.host -e SYNAPSE_REPORT_STATS=yes matrixdotorg/synapse:latest generate

```
Creating log config /data/my.matrix.host.log.config
Generating config file /data/homeserver.yaml
Generating signing key file /data/my.matrix.host.signing.key
A config file has been generated in '/data/homeserver.yaml' for server name 'my.matrix.host'. Please review this file and customise it to your needs.
```

So the file is generated in `/volume1/@docker/volumes/synapse-config/_data` but when I try to navigate there I get a permission denied error. I am ssh-ing using my `admin` account on the Synology.

How can I access this file through ssh CLI or DSM web interface or something else ?

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to root temporarily with **sudo -i**

When you are done, type **exit** to revert back to admin status.

Comment: This is probably more suited as a comment to the OP's question than a proper answer.